# jQuery Relative path issue

Tags: html, jquery, url, relative-url

I am currently am trying to get this below function working. I would like to use a relative path in order to add an active class for my different ul li a tag in my dom. The problem I am facing is that despite splitting the URL, it doesn't appear to be checking and comparing right part of the url and href. here is an of my HTML structure:

```
   <div class="parent-bar"> <ul> <li> 
  <a class="parent-link" href="/dummy-parent-2/">
         <div class="wrap">
             <span class="text">Parent page 2
             </span>
         </div> </a> <div id="child-menu-1" class="child-menu">
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <a href="/dummy-parent-2/dummy-child-1/" class="child-links">
                 <div class="wrap">
                     <span class="text">child page 1
                     </span>
                 </div>
                 </a>
             </li>
         </ul> </div> </li> </ul> </div>
```

and here is the jQuery supposed to be tracking the url:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var path = window.location.href;

  path = path.split("/");
 
  $(".parent-link").each(function() {
   if (this.href === path[3]) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
   }
  });
    if($('.parent-link').hasClass('active')){
      $('.child-links').addClass('active');
    }
 });
```

The console is not showing any errors. I can see the active class is not added. The reason I am looking to do this is to allow the children of the parent items to be active as well. I will apply the same principle to the children to track the parent's respective URL. if that makes sense.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: is it confirm that path[3] is not undefined?instead of checking with path you should check whether or not current url includes the href value,this will make it more simple

Comment: What does `console.log("[" + this.href + "]", "[" + path[3] + "]")` give you?  The `[`/`]` are to help you see if there's any spaces.

Comment: console.log("[" + this.href + "]", "[" + path[3] + "]") gives me undefined [p]. However, In the window if I do path[3] after storing the window.location.href it does give me what I am looking for. this is strange

Comment: @JatinParmar I am actually trying to do this. However I am unable to get the part that I want. The index of my parent link  should be 4. I did try to use this index and I didn't work.